# Thymeleaf Error: An Error Happened During Template Parsing

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I got an issue on the url mapping so don't focus on the codes inside my methods too much. This is my Controller:

```
@Autowired
ChannelService channelService;

@Autowired
RuleService ruleService;

@GetMapping("/config/{channelCode}/view/{ruleCode}")
    public String viewTable(@PathVariable String channelCode, @PathVariable String ruleCode, Authentication  authentication, ModelMap model) {
        UserPrincipal userPrincipal = (UserPrincipal) authentication.getPrincipal();
        ChannelDto channelDto = channelService.findByClientIdAndChannelCode(userPrincipal.getUser().getClient().getId(), channelCode);
        List<RuleStoreDto> storeDtos = ruleService.findAllCustomRuleStoreByClientIdAndChannelCode(userPrincipal.getUser().getClient().getId(), channelCode);
        model.addAttribute("channel", channelDto);
        model.addAttribute("stores", storeDtos);
        return "configuration/sales_channel_view";
    }

@GetMapping("/config/{channelCode}/create")
    public String createForm(@PathVariable String channelCode, Authentication authentication, ModelMap model) {     
        UserPrincipal userPrincipal = (UserPrincipal) authentication.getPrincipal();
        ChannelDto channelDto = channelService.findByClientIdAndChannelCode(userPrincipal.getUser().getClient().getId(), channelCode);
        model.addAttribute("channel", channelDto);
        return "configuration/sales_channel_create";
    }
        
@RequestMapping(value="/config/{channelCode}/create", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String postForm(
        @Valid @ModelAttribute("createForm") RuleStoreDto form, @PathVariable String channelCode, BindingResult result, Authentication  authentication, ModelMap model) {

        UserPrincipal userPrincipal = (UserPrincipal) authentication.getPrincipal();
        ChannelDto channelDto = channelService.findByClientIdAndChannelCode(userPrincipal.getUser().getClient().getId(), form.getChannelCode());
        model.addAttribute("channel", channelDto);
        
        try {
            form.setClientId(userPrincipal.getUser().getClient().getId());
            if(result.hasErrors()) {
                model.addAttribute("createForm", form);
                return "configuration/sales_channel_create";
            }
            customRuleService.save(form);
        }catch(Exception e) {
            model.addAttribute("err", e.getClass().getSimpleName());
            model.addAttribute("createForm", form);
            return "configuration/sales_channel_create";
        }
        return "configuration/sales_channel_create";
    }
```

This is a snippet from my sales_channel_view.html for the table view:

```
<div class="btn-group">
   <a class="btn btn-success"
      th:href="@{|/config/${channel.channelCode}/create|}">
      <i class="fa fa-plus">&nbsp; Create New</i>
   </a>
</div>
```

This is a snippet from my sales_channel_create.html for the form:

```
<form id="demo-form2" th:action="|@{/config/${channel.channelCode}/create}|" th:object="${createForm}" method="post" data-parsley-validate class="form-horizontal form-label-left">
   //stuff
</form>
```

So when I'm trying to visit the form (createForm) from the table (viewTable), my form is not fully shown & I got this error:

```
ERROR org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine - [THYMELEAF][http-nio-8080-exec-4] Exception processing template "configuration/sales_channel_create": An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/configuration/sales_channel_create.html]")
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/configuration/sales_channel_create.html]")
```

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: That is only the top of the exception. Usually, further down the exception stack is a more detailed explanation of what is wrong with your template. Either take a look yourself or update your question to include more of the exception.

Comment: Actually these are my company product's codes & I have a contract that I shouldn't leak these, so there are so many variables, url, file name, etc. that I faked on these codes to keep my company confidentiality. That's why I only paste the top of my exception, I can't really check all the exception one by one to replace real file names.

Comment: Then you have to look for yourself. Thymeleaf usually prints the useful errors further below.

Comment: `have a contract that I shouldn't leak these`
Then you should delete this post.

Comment: I know what you mean but I just confused with this error...

Comment: The Top-Level-Error just states that there is a problem with the template. Further down will be a more accurate description of what the engine is having trouble parsing.

Comment: Not gonna copy all but I found this:
Caused by: org.attoparser.ParseException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "storeCode" (template: "configuration/sales_channel_create" - line 46, col 133)

Comment: I found the problem. Each in my inputs in the form.html have th:value, so I deleted it & it finally shows all but the problem is, I use th:value for a reason to maintain inputted value after submit form with invalid value.

Answer (score 0):

Without the full exception, I can only speculate.

The pipe symbols (`|`) here seem wrong:

```
th:href="@{|/config/${channel.channelCode}/create|}">

th:action="|@{/config/${channel.channelCode}/create}|"
```

Because they are not part of [an valid URL](https://docs.microfocus.com/OMi/10.62/Content/OMi/ExtGuide/ExtApps/URL_encoding.htm) and whould need to be escaped as `%7C`.

Comment: I changed it, it still doesn't work with the same error